# How to set Session Affinity as "Client IP, Port and Protocol" at Kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, gcp-load-balancer

I have a Kubernetes service at GKE. Currently it has Session Affinity:ClientIP. and in GCP Load Balancer Console, it is shown as "Client IP"

What value should I set it as so that in GCP Load Balancer Console, it will be shown as "Client IP, Port and Protocol"?

All the documents I saw mention that
Session Affinity can be assigned as "ClientIP" or "no" (by default). none of them tell me there is a third option, while if you check GCP Load balancer, it has multiple options for Session Affinity: None; Client IP; Client IP and Protocol; Client IP, Port and Protocol

this is the service file:

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: test
  name: test
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/load-balancer-type: Internal
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
    - port: XXX
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: XXX
      name: XXX
  selector:
    app: XXX
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
```

Answer (score 0):

Session affinity, sometimes referred to as sticky sessions, associates all requests coming from an end-user with a single pod. This means that all traffic from a client to a pod will be  directed to the same pod.

> If you want to make sure that connections from a particular client are
> passed to the same Pod each time, you can select the session affinity
> based on the client's IP addresses by setting
> service.spec.sessionAffinity to "ClientIP"

From the [Latest Kubernetes API ServiceSpec v1 core](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.20/#servicespec-v1-core):

**sessionAffinity**

> Supports "ClientIP" and "None". Used to maintain session affinity.
> Enable client IP based session affinity. **Must be ClientIP or None**.
> Defaults to None. More info:
> https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#virtual-ips-and-service-proxies

So, `ClientIP` or `None` - you dont have 3rd choice.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/backend-service shows Internal TCP/UDP Load Balancing has above 4 options. how can I implement the last option using Kubernetes service?

Comment: that is fine, Thanks Vitalii.